# Get 5 questions from each category, and if fewer than 5 - repeat exisiting until 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have questions belonging to categories.

I want to insert 5 questions from each category to an array, and if there aren't 5 in a category - then I need to insert duplicates such that I have 5 from each category.

If there were 5 or more questions in each category I would use the following code, but when I only have 1 or 2 questions in a category, obviously it doesn't work:

```
a = []
Category.all.each do |category|
  category.questions.order(position: :asc).limit(5).each do |question|
    a << question
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly understand you

```
a = []
Category.all.each do |category|
  questions = category.questions.order(position: :asc).limit(5)
  a += ([questions] * 5).first(5)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Category.pluck(:questions).flat_map do |questions|
  questions.order(postion: :asc).limit(5).cycle.take(5)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = []
Category.all.each do |category|
  ca = []
  category.questions.order(position: :asc).limit(5).each do |question|
    ca << question
  end
  if !ca.empty?;
    ca *= 5
    ca = ca[0, 5]
    ca.each do |question| a << question end
  end
end
```